# Floating point addition and division

Tags: loops, floating-point, floating-point-precision

For this code segment

```
double count = 0.0;
while( count != 1.0)
{count += 1.0/3;}
```

I was wondering what parts of (IEEE 754) would cause count 3: to be 1.0 instead of .9999999999999999. I realize that the general reason would be rounding due to an infinite number of binary digits but if anyone could go into more detail to explain the (IEEE 754) specifics behind this I would appreciate it.

Comment: What kind of specifics are you looking for?  You seem to have summed it up nicely already.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if their is any direct terminology for this kind of occurrence as I'm not sure my professor would accept my reasoning for why this turns out be be 1.0 when my only answer is "because rounding".

Comment: I don't believe IEEE-754 guarantees that code like that will ever succeed. The first time around, it probably won't (at least in the general case - it may with certain specific divisors), on most modern platforms, but I suppose if you let it run long enough, after wrapping around infinity a few times, it might manage to hit exactly the right bit pattern, though...

Answer (score 0):

There is no general rule that ensures that adding `n` copies of `1.0/n` will result in exactly `1.0`. This can be explored by changing `n` in the following program:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 3;
        double[] counts = new double[n+1];
        for(int i=1; i<counts.length; i++){
            counts[i] = counts[i-1]+1.0/n;
        }
        for(double count : counts){
            System.out.println(new BigDecimal(count));
        }
    }
}
```

For `n=3` it prints:

```java
0
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625
1
```

The first addition adds to zero. The second addition is a simple doubling, so it is also exact. The third and final addition involves rounding, but rounds to `1.0`. The exact result of that addition is:

```java
0.999999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
```

It is closer to 1.0 than it is to the next value down:

```java
0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

so round-to-nearest rounds to 1.0.

However, changing `n` to `7` results in:

```java
0
0.142857142857142849212692681248881854116916656494140625
0.28571428571428569842538536249776370823383331298828125
0.428571428571428547638078043746645562350749969482421875
0.5714285714285713968507707249955274164676666259765625
0.7142857142857141905523121749865822494029998779296875
0.8571428571428569842538536249776370823383331298828125
0.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
```

Running the original program modified to add `1.0/7` would have resulted in an infinite loop. `count` would have increased until it was so big that adding `1.0/7` would round to the old value, and then stuck at that value.

Comment: It's not guaranteed for multiplication, either.  Try `1.0 / 49 * 49`.

Comment: @dan04 Indeed. It is generally best to assume rounding error, and note the few special cases that are sure to be exact.